# Django - Change a ForeignKey relation to OneToOne

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-south

I am using South with my Django app.  I have two models that I am changing from having a `ForeignKey` relation to having a `OneToOneField` relation. When I ran this migration on my dev database, it ran fine. When the migrations get ran as part of creating a test database, the latest migration fails with a MySQL 1005 error: "Can't create table mydb.#sql-3249_1d (errno: 121)". Doing some Googling revealed that this is usually a problem with trying to add a constraint with the same name as an existing constraint. The specific line in the migration that it fails on is:

The relation was changed from:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    othermodel = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel)
```

to

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    othermodel = models.OneToOneField(OtherModel)
```

which generated the following statements in the migration:

```
db.alter_column('myapp_mymodel', 'othermodel_id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField')(to=orm['myapp.OtherModel'], unique=True))

db.create_unique('myapp_mymodel', ['othermodel_id'])
```

But instead of failing on the `create_unique` call, it is failing on the `alter_column` call. I ran the following command to see what SQL was being generated:

```
python manage.py migrate myapp 0010 --db-dry-run --verbosity=2
```

and it printed out

```
myapp:0010_auto__chg_field_mymodel_othermodel__add_unique_mymodel
   = ALTER TABLE `myapp_mymodel` ADD CONSTRAINT `myapp_mymodel_othermodel_id_uniq` UNIQUE (`othermodel_id`) []
   = SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; []
   = ALTER TABLE `myapp_mymodel` ADD CONSTRAINT `myapp_mymodel_othermodel_id_uniq` UNIQUE (`othermodel_id`) []
```

It seems strange that it is trying to run the `ADD CONSTRAINT` twice, but if I remove the `db.create_unique` call, no SQL is generated when I run it with `--db-dry-run`, but I still get the error if I run it for real.

I am at a loss here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have created exactly the same migration some days ago and it ran fine. Could you try the same code with a different database backend (I did it on a PostgreSQL database).
Also, check your South version.

Comment: Wish I could help - I made the change, it generated the same python and SQL code, and the migration ran just fine, using mysql 5.1.56 for win32.

Comment: Ask this on the South mailing list and you're pretty likely to find the answer.

Answer (score 14):

You actually don't need a migration at all. OneToOne and ForeignKey relations have a compatible database schema under the hook: a simple column witht the other object ID in one of the table.

Just fake the migration with `migrate --fake` if you don't want to enter in the trouble of telling south to ignore this change.

Comment: And if you're at all in doubt that @e-satis is correct about this, take this tidbit from the code (`django.db.models.fields.related`): "A OneToOneField is essentially the same as a ForeignKey, with the exception that always carries a 'unique' constraint with it" And note that OneToOne actually inherits from ForeignKey with only a few minor tweaks.

Comment: To be precise, changing a field from ForeignKey to OneToOneField HAS an effect on the database (at least on those supporting constraints), that shouldn't be skipped: a ForeignKey is not unique, while OneToOneField is. In Django 1.8 - using the native command `makemigrations` on mysql backend - I had no problems at all. The migration correctly deleted the previous non-unique index on the field at the DB level, and set the new unique index.

Comment: Same comment as @AugustoDestrero with Django 3.2

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would try would be to add a `db.delete_unique(...)` in various places to see if I could hack it.

Failing that, I'd split it up into 3 migrations:

1. a schema migration to add a new column for the OneToOne
2. a data migration to copy all FK values from old column over to new
3. a schema migration to remove the old column, which then I'd edit manually to include a command to rename the new column to the same as the old one.

Comment: this should be the correct answer, very helpful blueprint

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @e-satis that the goal here is to fake a migration, but I suggest a different approach if you're working with a team.

If you create a migration then `--fake` it, all your team members will need to remember to `--fake` it as well. If any of them don't do this when they upgrade, you're in trouble.

A better approach is to create an empty migration, then migrate it:

```
manage.py schemamigration yourapp --empty fake_migration_of_foreign_key_to_onetoone
manage.py migrate  # Like you always do!
```